# Swift How to merge video and audio into a one mp4 file

Tags: audio, video, swift3, avfoundation, avasset

I want to merge video captured by AVCaptureSession() and audio recorded by AVAudioRecorder() into one mp4 file ..

I tried this solution 
[Swift Merge audio and video files into one video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984474/swift-merge-audio-and-video-files-into-one-video)

and this [Merging audio and video Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404634/merging-audio-and-video-swift)

but both of them didn't work. They both gave me the same error : Thread1 : Signal SIGABRT

So what is the right way to merge audio and video ?

**UPDATE:-**

I found where the app crashes every time. It crashes on the code line that tries to get an **AVAssetTrack** from **AVAsset**

```
func merge(audio:URL, withVideo video : URL){

    // create composition
    let mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    // Create the video composition track.
    let mutableCompositionVideoTrack : AVMutableCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    // Create the audio composition track.
    let mutableCompositionAudioTrack : AVMutableCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    // create media assets and tracks
    let videoAsset = AVAsset(url: video)  
    let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] // ** always crashes here ** //

    let audioAsset = AVAsset(url: audio) 
    let audioAssetTrack = audioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] // ** always crashes here ** //

....

}
```

Comment: Always check for count of elements in the array before subscript the items. like: if  videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).count > 0 { let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] }

Comment: You can also implement a safe subscript, that returns an optional (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings)